# Should compiling c++ in Xubuntu 19.04 be different then compiling c++ in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

Will there ever be a case where C++ code compiles with no errors in Ubuntu 18.04 and not compile in Xubuntu 19.04. My original guess was no but then a professor told me about there being some linker issues that may cause that. Also let me also add that the code is compiled using the same std and using g++.

Comment: Depending on the specific versions of the compiler toolchain, `g++` by default, yes the results of compilation could be different

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 has `g++-7.4.0` ... Ubuntu 19.04 has `g++-8.3.0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will there ever be a case where C++ code compiles with no errors in Ubuntu 18.04 and not compile in Xubuntu 19.04.

Possibly, but it only arises in corner cases. Most C++ code won't be affected.

I think it depends on GCC version. Around that time GCC started enabling PIE by default, and it caused some linking issues. See, for example, [Initial SUPERCOP Haswell results for round 2](https://groups.google.com/a/list.nist.gov/d/msg/pqc-forum/kiMo-1jBwDI/KS8VtDwWAgAJ). From the mailing list message:

> ... The rest of this message explains the -fPIC -fPIE above. On
>   exactly the same long-term-support version of Ubuntu, with the
>   supposedly compatible system-provided versions of gcc and clang, if
>   you run
>
> ```
>    gcc -c x.c; clang -c y.c; gcc -o x x.o y.o
> ```
>
> where x.c says
>
> ```
>    #include <stdio.h>
>    extern int thenumber(void);
>    int main() { printf("%d\n",thenumber()); return 0; }
> ```
>
> and y.c says
>
> ```
>    static int myconstant = 5;
>    int thenumber(void) { return myconstant; }
> ```
>
> then compilation fails, while doing
>
> ```
>    gcc -c x.c; clang -c y.c; clang -o x x.o y.o
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
>    gcc -c x.c; gcc -c y.c; gcc -o x x.o y.o
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
>    clang -c x.c; clang -c y.c; clang -o x x.o y.o
> ```
>
> works fine. The underlying problem is compiler-writer mismanagement of
>   an ongoing transition to
>
> - -fPIC: compiling libraries as "position-independent code" (this is typically advertised as being important for shared libraries);
> - -fPIE: compiling main() etc. as position-independent code (this is typically advertised as being important for the claimed security
>     benefits of address-space layout randomization); and
> - -pie: linking position-independent executables.
>
> Code that's compiled as position-independent code can be linked into
>   position-dependent executables or position-independent executables. A
>   correctly managed transition would have consisted of
>
> - turning on -fPIC and -fPIE by default,
> - issuing automatic *warnings* for any position-dependent code,
> - waiting a specified number of years for people to get rid of any   previously compiled position-dependent code, and finally
> - turning on -pie by default.
>
> What happened instead was gcc suddenly turning on -pie, clumsily
>   breaking all existing position-dependent code and even managing to
>   break compatibility with clang on the same system---clang still
>   produces position-dependent code, and then gcc fails to produce an
>   executable. This is also why gcc now breaks
>   crypto_kem/ntruhrss701/avx2.